# Choosing best modelling practices

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models, experiment-design

I am modelling some behavioural data in R to determine the best parameters for explaining foraging success of marine animals. I have both fine scale parameters relating to the direct individual (e.g. dive depth, trip length) and broad-scale parameters (e.g. temperature, wind, chlorophyll a).

To avoid overfitting, I currently have 2 models, one modelling fine-scale and one modelling broad-scale predictor variables and I am using model averaging to determine the best set of predictors for each model.

My question is: Can I use the broad and the fine-scale models as initial testing of the best parameters to include, and then put all the best parameters together in a single model? I've tried this out and it provides a good model with a higher predictive capacity but would this be considered bad practice? I haven't seen this done in other work (and certainly never done it myself).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method of two separate models to fight overfitting is unknown to me, and I also don't really see how it should succeed. But since you have good results, you should give it a try.

Nevertheless, I would have started with a model that contains all parameters (fine and large scale). Then, there are many methods for both selecting the appropriate parameters ([random forest variable importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html), ARD (e.g. [relevance vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_vector_machine)), [spike and slab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike-and-slab_regression), and many more, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)), and for fighting overfitting (e.g. [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)), [Bayesian methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_statistics), or [appropriate information criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Criteria)) that can be applied to this model.